# What does "DNS Record Published / DNS Record not found" by mxtoolbox means?

Tags: email, dns

I am making a MX Lookup and getting this message from MXToolbox:

[image: Message from MXToolbox]

The instructions with what is wrong and what can be done about it are very cryptic.

How can somebody publish their DNS records and get rid of this error?

Thanks!

p.s. Initially I have wrongly posted the question on Stack Overflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75799465/what-does-dns-record-published-dns-record-not-found-by-mxtoolbox-means. I hope now I am right here.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on "more info"? What does it tell you?

Comment: What is the domain? Who hosts the domain(registrar)? Who is the mail provider? Do you know what the value of your MX record is supposed to be?

Comment: @DavidPostill: the more info was just mentioning this: DNS not published (should of been clear enough...)


Thank you all. I have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

From the mxtoolbox website
[DNS Record Published](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/dns/dns-record-published) :

> More Information About Dns Record Published
>
> We did not find a DNS record published for this domain or hostname.

It means that your DNS setup is missing details, or perhaps that your
DNS update, if very recent, hasn't finished propagating.

For more in-depth analysis, we would need to know your domain name.
You could get yourself perhaps more detailed error message by using
[IntoDNS](https://intodns.com/).
More tools can be found in
[5 Online Tools to Check DNS Records](https://geekflare.com/online-tools-to-check-dns-records/).

Answer (score 0):

Stupid be: it was of course the DNS.

Yes, I have a complicated setup as some I self host under some subdomains (aliases) and I need DynamicDNS (provided by Dynu, which is also my registrar) while some other services, mail included, are hosted online. And while on my hoster the MX records were maintained, I did not thought that I need to maintain them also on my registrar. I had actually a wildcard A record and, this is my mistake, I thought this should be enough.

Solution: define MX record on the registrar. Problem Solved. Thank you all for the comments: they lead me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

If it's the DNS of an ISP this result could also mean that they filter out requests from outside their own address pool, so only their own users can resolve addresses for e.g. their PBX.

You can try it with the domain "tel.t-online.de" from the German ISP Telekom.
If you are not on a Telekom line you will get the same "DNS Record Published / DNS Record not found" result.